# Can we have a UTC clock in the chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat

In the menu bar in the achievements tab I can access the current UTC time, which is good, since I am not living in that time zone.

In chat this bar is missing. Instead messages are marked with my local time zone. In the transcript, however, the time stamps are again UTC, but there is no way to tell which time it is at the moment - which is sometimes a little confusing when you are reading the transcript of the same day.

I would appreciate having a clock on these pages.

Comment: Holy heck, there is an UTC time indicator in the Achievements dropdown! What even is it doing there! Good to know; cool! :D

Answer (score 5):

I've made a userscript for this here: https://gist.github.com/hyper-neutrino/53ef6e1f48fea9d5a5daeb27e6422b42. It works in MSE, MSO, and SE chat in rooms and in the transcript.

In a chat room, it puts a box to the right of the chat buttons (it moves appropriately when new buttons appear) showing the UTC time.

On a transcript page, it updates the "all times are in UTC" message to also show what the current time in UTC is.